# Zika concerns travelling to Puerto Rico?

Tags: health, insects, puerto-rico, zika

I am a United States male that will be taking a trip to Puerto Rico in two weeks. This will be one of my first airplane trips, certainly the farthest away. Recent news has focused on Puerto Rico for its widespread outbreak of Zika Virus, with sources like NPR citing up to 1500 new cases a week.

Is there anything, other than CDC recommended prevention techniques (i.e long sleeves and bug spray) I should do during/after this trip? Should I visit a doctor after just to be sure? I am not incredibly concerned with the health impact if I were to contract the disease, the symptoms appear mild and pass fairly quickly, I do however have a girlfriend I would prefer not to pass it to. Is there a chance of increased scrutiny trying to fly home? Seeing as the few cases in Miami are making national news daily it seems like officials want to track any possible case in the US, would they want to make sure it is not being brought back by travelers?

Comment: You should be far-far more worried about other tropical diseases, see: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/31639/23144. Same situation as with the "swine flu" hysteria.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "increased scrutiny", Puerto Rico is part of the US and flights are domestic. If you are concerned about transmitting Zika to your girlfriend, you could use barrier contraception (a condom) after you return until you are sure you didn't catch it.